# jQuery appending 300 divs in for loop has extra top and bottom margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not really sure why there's extra space above and below my boxes that I'm appending in a simple for loop.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    Snake
  </div>
  <div id="game-container"></div>
</body>
```

CSS: (I tried a lot of go-tos)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
html, body {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: rgb(0, 50, 105);
}

#game-container {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.one-square {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = '<div class="one-square"></div>';

    for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
      $('#game-container').append(div);
    }
});
```

Clearly I'm missing something obvious. Quick codepen to demonstrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrperX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `line-height:0px;` to your `#game-conatiner` div.

```
#game-container {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height:0px; /* ADDED */
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/weqaqvxh/)

**Explanation:** While your div has some `line-height` by default which has height more than your `one-square` div's so it has space above and below. Adding `line-height:0px` it will remove it.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Bannon Glad that it helped you!

Comment: What `line-height:0px;` does ?

Comment: @divy3993 I'm curious, Is this preferable to `float:left`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D, But I guess it is somehow related to `inline-block` elements. `block` elements does not work this way..(Guess :P)

Comment: Yeah that seems, Ive always used floats in these cases myself. Im just wondering if setting the line height might have some undesired effects down the road or if this is a better way, no worries :)

Comment: As far as you do not have text inside it's good, same as in this case. Else `float:left;` is prefreable.

Comment: Also in this if OP adds something else than just these square blocks, it's better not to have `float:left;`. Else `float:left` is also pretty handy and good.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.one-square {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

To:

```
.one-square {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

See [this updated code-pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwZKWw)

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 0em;` for the `#game-container`.

```
#game-container {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  line-height: 0em;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: What `line-height: 0em;` does ?

Comment: Its reduces the distance between each lines to 0. The small boxes are placed as elements `display: inline-block`. If you increase the line-height, it will increase the distance between each line of blocks

Comment: @RayonDabre That's not *exactly* correct: [**"On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element."**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) not the distance between lines. Though that is the *effect* in this case.